# Cannot convert IEnumerable to IList error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm building a linq query based on form inputs from the user. I have a view that expects an IList of type "trace".

This approach may be entirely wrong, but I'm getting the following error with the below code

Error   7   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I don't understand this becuase I never cast traces as enumerable in the first pace.

Ultimately, I just want to query the traces entity and return a list to the view.

```
IList<trace> traces = new List<trace>();

//by users
if (form["reps"] != null)
{
    List<string> reps = new List<string>(form["reps"].Split(','));
    traces = traces.Where(s => reps.Contains(s.repslist));
}
//by start date
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(form["homefrom"]))
{
    DateTime sdate = Convert.ToDateTime(form["homefrom"]);
    traces = traces.Where(t => t.tracedate >= sdate);
}

return PartialView("_tracescontainer", traces);
```

EDIT

I tried the below - everything compiles, no errors, in google inspector, the post shows pending without erroring out. I've waiting for about 10 minutes. When debugging, I step through and the step never gets to the line IList tracelist = traces.ToList();

There is no error, it just goes out of the breakpoint as though the operation is complete, but no results are sent to the browser.

```
IEnumerable<trace> traces = db.traces;

//by users
if (form["reps"] != null)
{
    List<string> reps = new List<string>(form["reps"].Split(','));
    traces = traces.Where(s => reps.Contains(s.repslist));
}
//by start date
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(form["homefrom"]))
{
    DateTime sdate = Convert.ToDateTime(form["homefrom"]);
    traces = traces.Where(t => t.tracedate >= sdate);
}

IList<trace> tracelist = traces.ToList();

return PartialView("_tracescontainer", tracelist);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Where` returns an `IEnumerable`, not a `List`.  Since you don't actually need your `traces` variable to be an `IList` here, you should type it as an `IEnumerable` to avoid the needless overhead of populating the results of your query into a list just so that you can iterate over that list and populate a *new* list.

If it's important to materialize the results of the query into a list at some later point in time, after you have finished constructing the query, then you can call `ToList` on the `IEnumerable` to build up a `List` with the results.

On top of the above, it appears that your actual data source is an `IQueryable` representing a query against a database, not an in memory collection.  You should use `IQueryable` as the type of your variable.  This will build up a *query*, rather than the results of the query, so that after building that query you can request the filtered results from your database, rather than pulling your entire database table into memory and filtering it there.

Comment: Thanks Servy - I tried that originally. Please see my edit in the original question.

Comment: @tintyethan The fact that `traces` actually comes from a LINQ to something query provider means that this should be an `IQueryable`, not an `IEnumerable`.  You should be building a query that will be executed against your database, not pulling down the whole list in memory and filtering in your application.  As for your code, it won't even compile as you have two local variables with the same name.  You're not allowed to do that.

Comment: What is the proper form to instantiate the variable? Is this correct IQueryable<trace> traces = db.traces;? Also, what two locals with same name are you referring to? The code does compile.

Comment: @tintyethan That's just fine, yes.  Earlier on you had two `traces` local variables, you have since edited one to `traceList`.  With that change, the code that you've shown is just fine.  If you're not getting any results, then odds are nothing is matching your query criteria.

Comment: Thanks - the issue is not that it returns empty, the POST never completes - it remains pending.

Comment: @tintyethan Then that's still an issue with something that you haven't shown here.